# Configuration of UDPbinding in Universal App framework

Tags: wcf, win-universal-app, .net-core

I am migrating an "old" code from Framework 4.6 to universal app code to consume a WCF Service.I have different bindings, NetTCPbinding is working ok, when configuring my binding for consuming an UDPbinding from WCF in 4.6 framework I cannot find UDPbinding in System.ServiceModel anymore in .NET for Universal Apps.
I need a communication as fast as possible and .nettcpbinding seems not enough.
I have added as reference System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Channels
Any idea?
This is my code from the client in .NETCORE for Universal for configuring the connection to WCF Service:

```
try
    {

     //Here I cannot find the UDPbinding!!!!!
     UdpBinding myBinding = new UdpBinding();
     EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress("soap.udp://" + ipAddress + ":" + portNo);
     ChannelFactory<IService1> chn = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, addr);
     IService1 conn = chn.CreateChannel();
     return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

My server service configuration routine is this:

```
  private void ConfigService(string portNo) {

        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFComm), new Uri("http://localhost:/XXX/XXX"));
        // Add service endpoint
        UdpBinding myBinding = new UdpBinding();
        string address = "soap.udp://localhost:" + portNo;
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), myBinding, address);
        try {host.Open();} catch(Exception ex) {} 
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it is not supported only BasicHttp

Comment: Hi, I have a local network and I need high speed (like some online videogame)which arquitecture you recommend?

Comment: Maybe you can use Signal R

Comment: I do not think so. I am communicating a 4.5 framework with an Universal App. My idea was to use UDP, but I cannot find compatible classes from botr frameworks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets In this link they talk about Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener socketListener but it seems is not compatible framework 4 System.Net.Sockets

Comment: @ronconsoda How about NetTcpBinding.

Comment: I already have this binding, but its not so quick for my purposes ( updating position every 24 ms)